# why are strings added as chars in this example python?

Tags: python, list

```
l = []
d1 = 'string1'
d2 = 'string2'
ds = [d1, d2]
ds
['string1', 'string2']
for d in ds:
    l+=d
    
l
['s', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g', '1', 's', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g', '2']
```

Since d1 and d2 are separate strings, why are still added as chars? we add them in the loop as strings, separate entities, I expect list l to be

```
l = ['string1', 'string2']
```

Comment: Because `+=` on a list is *extend*, not append.

Comment: `l += [d]` (or `l += (d,)`) would work (although it would not be an efficient thing to do at scale compared to `l.append(d)`).

Comment: @jonrsharpe, thx u , i totally forgot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `.append()` instead of `+=`:

```
for d in ds:
    l.append(d)
```

`+=` extends your strings, instead of just appending them to the end of your list.